# How do I pass the data to a ResultSet from a MySQL Query?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

When I run a query it returns the following results

```
periodEndingDate | TotalMin | TimesheetId |
-------------------------------------------
2007-08-19       |  38.000  |            1|
2010-09-17       |  26.500  |            2|
```

So, I have the following  way of getting the values, I know the third one is getting it right (The Number one) but how can I cast to the second and first columns ? (Date) and (Float or Double), the TotalMin is an addition of several columns (minutes) of ints divided by 60.

This is what I have

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT periodEndingDate, 
              ((minutesMon+minutesTue+minutesWed+minutesThu+"
              +"minutesFri+minutesSat+minutesSun)/60) as TotalMin, 
              TimesheetId FROM timesheet WHERE employeeID='"+empID+"';");

for (; rs.next();) {
                ArrayList tmData = new ArrayList();
                tmData.add((String) rs.getObject(1));

                tmData.add((String) rs.getObject(2));

                                       //for the timesheet id
                tmData.add(((Number) rs.getObject(3)).intValue()); 

                TimeSheetData.add(tmData);
            }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rs.getDate()` or `rs.getTimestamp()` for the first column.

You can use `rs.getDouble()` for the second one.

This is better than using rs.getObject() and then casting it. I'd change your 3rd column to `rs.getInt()`

Note : rs.getInt() and rs.getDouble() return primitives that get autoboxed when they are added to your list.

Comment: So would it be (Date) rs.getDate(); ?

Comment: rs.getDate() returns a java.sql.Date object .. which is a subclass of java.util.Date. No need to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are after

Create a class

```
class Timesheet
    {
        //periodEndingDate | TotalMin | TimesheetId 
        private Date periodEndingDate;
        private BigDecimal totalMin;
        private int timesheetId;

        //---------GETTERS AND SETTERS
    }
```

Then in your code above replace for loop with this

```
List<Timesheet> tmData = new ArrayList<Timesheet>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Timesheet timesheet = new Timesheet();
         //periodEndingDate,TotalMin and TimesheetId should be the name of columns in the table  
        timesheet.setPeriodEndingDate( rs.getDate("periodEndingDate"));
        timesheet.setTotalMin( rs.getBigDecimal("TotalMin"));
        timesheet.setTimesheetId(rs.getInt("TimesheetId"));
        tmData.add(timesheet);  
}
```

Comment: Yes, I will try this tomorrow with more time.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just do:

```
tmData.add((DateTime) rs.getObject(1));
tmData.add((decimal) rs.getObject(2));
```

What am I missing?